# How to make changes to a managed packaged when the security review is "In progress?"

Tags: apex, managed-package

I started a Managed Package security review and I need to make some changes to the code. Specifically I need to add some JSON encoding to a certain place to prevent an XSS vulnerability. Is there a way to make a change to the package version which I already submitted or do I need to somehow upload a new version and make a substitution?

Clearly I don't want to risk having to pay Security Fee again! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Fee is charged only once so worst case you will fail security review and you will have to resubmit the same .Be assured that you won't be charged again .

On the other note on making changes you will have to create a new version of package and resubmit newer version .

You can schedule an office hour with security review team and request them to consider new package version.

Comment: So - for the version that's listed as "submitted" should I cancel it and resubmit a new submission? And in that case will I have to fill everything out again? I.e. add false positive report, info security policy document, etc?

Comment: Yes you can cancel that submission and yes you will have to fill all info again and attach document again

Comment: Don't worry, surely you will not charged twice. As salesforce clearly mentioned about the security fee viz. 2700$ is one time charged. So if you want any changes then add those in the next releases. All the best!